# Android new activity not starting

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I wrote this code following the skeleton of Reto Meier's "Professional Android 4 Application Development" and some slide of my professor, but i can't understand why the new activity (PreferencesActivity, fully coded) is not starting and is not raising any kind of errors: in the VM it just won't do anything when i press "Preferences" in the standard android menu I created.
I added the new activity in app's manifest correctly (just name, label, theme and screen orientation).

Here's the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnValueChangeListener {

static final private int MENU_PREFERENCES = Menu.FIRST+1;

...

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, MENU_PREFERENCES, Menu.NONE, "Preferences");
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsitemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case (MENU_PREFERENCES): {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
...
}
```

The only strange thing I get is this warning in Logcat

```
06-20 14:50:49.760: W InputManagerService(699): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41219950
```

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution? I am also having same problem right now, although it was working just a few days ago. No idea what is the problem right now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of them

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreferencesActivity.class);

Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
```

But it's better to use 1st one because in 2nd one memory leakage problem may occour and also just add this line in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this` you could use `getApplicationContext()`, it gets you the context of the application object for the currents process.

Try this....

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreferencesActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

This May Help You..

Comment: `getapplicationContext()` as the name suggests gives you the context of the application object for the currents process not the context of your activity. From Android's documenatation : 

**Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process. This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context, that is tied to the lifetime of the process rather than the current component.**

Comment: Not working, got again
06-21 09:49:30.332: W/InputManagerService(392): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4122fb08

Answer (score 0):

Your Code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, PreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
return true;
```

Instead of `this` you need to pass `MainActivity.this`

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
return true;
```

Issue is Proper context is not passing so its not starting Activity.

Comment: Not working, got again
06-21 09:49:30.332: W/InputManagerService(392): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4122fb08

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass MainActivity

```
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreferencesActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  return true;
```

Better to use menu

```
   @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   

       Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected()");

      switch (item.getItemId()) {        
   case android.R.id.yourId:            
    finish();      
    return true; 
   case R.id.Yourid:
    return true;
    default:            
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write
`startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class));`

write your activity name in NextActivity.class